# Concatenating IObservables which depend on the previous IObservable output

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I have a function `IObservable<SomeEvent> SomeColdStream(int? someParam)` that I need to call sequentially multiple times, but the `someParam` argument needs to come from the last event of the previous `SomeColdStream` call, and I need a single Observable in the end with all `SomeEvents` emitted by it.

My first try is the `.Concat` combinator:

```
SomeColdStream(null).Concat(SomeColdStream(<<insert information from the last SomeEvent of first SomeColdStream call>>));
```

but I could not find out how to carry information from one stream to the next.

My next try was to use `Publish`:

```
var firstStream = SomeColdStream(null).Publish().RefCount()

var previous = firstStream().LastAsync();

firstStream.Concat(previous.SelectMany(p => SomeColdStream(p));
```

I have not yet tested this, because it seems a bit 'unelegant' for Rx and I wanted to ask if somebody knows how I could achieve what I want with a better approach?

I know that I could mix IObservables with "async/await" but that breaks my testing which heavily relies on the `Testschedulers` which are not supported by "async/await".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to combine the `LastAsync` and `SelectMany` operators like this:

```
IObservable<SomeEvent> sequence = SomeColdStream(null)
    .LastAsync()
    .SelectMany(x => SomeColdStream(x));
```

...but this will propagate only the second stream's messages, and all the messages of the first stream will be suppressed. This problem can probably be fixed by merging the first stream to the above sequence, but this also requires the `Publish` the first stream so that it's not subscribed twice. Below is an extension method `ConcatWithResult` that should do the correct thing:

```
static IObservable<T> ConcatWithResult<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, IObservable<T>> continuation)
{
    return source.Publish(published => published.Merge(published
        .LastAsync()
        .SelectMany(x => continuation(x))));
}
```

Alternative implementation, using the "side-effecty" `Do` operator:

```
static IObservable<T> ConcatWithResult<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, IObservable<T>> continuation)
{
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        (T Value, bool HasValue) last = default;
        return source
            .Do(x => last = (x, true))
            .Concat(Observable.Defer(() =>
            {
                if (!last.HasValue) throw new InvalidOperationException();
                return continuation(last.Value);
            }));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm not sure this solves my problem, because it looks like I would lose all the events from the first stream? Imagine like what the output of concat would look like, but where I get the last event from the previous call.

Comment: @Ynv you are right, I updated the answer. Hopefully now it's correct (I haven't tested the code).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this:

```
IObservable<TSource> Expand<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IObservable<TSource>> selector)
```

Then you can build your query like this:

```
IObservable<SomeEvent> query =
    SomeColdStream(null)
        .TakeLast(1)
        .Expand(x => SomeColdStream(x.SomeValue).TakeLast(1));
```

Let's try an example:

```
IObservable<int> Demonstration(int? input)
{
    if (input == null)
        return Observable.Return(1);
    else if (input < 5)
        return new[] { input.Value + 1, input.Value * 3 }.ToObservable();
    else
        return Observable.Empty<int>();
}
```

Now I can write this query:

```
IObservable<int> query =
    Demonstration(null)
        .TakeLast(1)
        .Expand(x => Demonstration(x).TakeLast(1));
```

That produces the sequence `1, 3, 9`.

Comment: I think that the OP wants to invoke the `selector` only for the last element of the `source` sequence, not for all the elements.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I misread that. I'm not sure exactly which last elements the OP needs, but I've modified my code to report on the last elements of each call. Oddly enough `LastAsync()` failed on my test code where `TaskLast(1)` worked.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - No, I made a mistake. Not odd at all. `TakeLast(1)` succeeds when the observable is empty. `LastAsync()` requires at least one value.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73878947/concatenating-iobservables-which-depend-on-the-previous-iobservable-output/73922442?noredirect=1#comment130452801_73879781) comment by the OP, they don't want just to invoke the `selector` with the last element as argument. They also want the propagation of all elements, from both the `source` and the secondary sequences. And I think that the selector should be invoked once, not recursively.